# чтение dbf файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbf

При чтении из dbf файла получаю dataframe Pandas, в нем вот такую строку:
`b'0.00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`
с вероятностью 99.99% - это кириллица. Но вот из какой кодировки и как это вернуть в человеческий вид - загадка.

Comment: Конкретно в этой байтовой строке нет кириллицы. Нужно просто обрезать нулевые байты и декодировать из набора байт строку: `b'0.00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'.rstrip(b'\0').decode()` - получится просто `'0.00'`. Там где есть кириллица - нужно смотреть в какой она кодировке, и указать нужную кодировку как аргумент метода decode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В dbf для русского языка используются две кодировки - CP866 (она же кодировка DOS, она же OEM) и WIN1251.

Если приведете строку, содержащую осмысленный текст, то могу подсказать какая из двух.

Конкретно эта строка содержит только ASCII-символы и завершающие нулевые символы, для нее кодировка не важна.

Comment: соответственно, не важно b'0.00\x00\x00' или b'0.00\x00 - это integer 0. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov скорее float 0.0

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov, да это число. В dBase тип NUMBER хранится как строка